# Weblogic work manager for a specific web services inside a web application

Tags: weblogic, jax-ws, workmanagers

Inside a web application, I have 2 web services and 2 servlets. Some of these components are internal so we don't want to limit them but one client facing web services needs to be limited because it can crashes the server if too many clients call it. I have been trying to do it in the web.xml as you can see in the code below with no success unfortunately. The JSP servlet in dispatch properly to the right work manager but the sample web services is going to the default work manager.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Normaljsp</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>normal.jsp</jsp-file>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>wl-dispatch-policy</param-name>
        <param-value>WorkManager-Global</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Sample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mk.sample.WebServiceSample</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>wl-dispatch-policy</param-name>
        <param-value>WorkManager-Endpoints</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Sample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>sample</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How can I isolate this last sample web service with its own work manager ? 
Thanks,